# Check a function pointer by bool() and (bool) of C++

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers

I saw C++ code like this:

```
if(bool(function_pointer))
```

Where `function_pointer` is

```
typedef boost::function<bool (const int&)> Checker;
```

I'm wondering what's the difference between

```
 bool(function_pointer)
```

and

```
(bool)function_pointer
```

Comment: Those are both [*explicit type conversions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) and mean the same thing.

Comment: The casting is also not needed. If used when a boolean value is expected (like in a condition) then [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) have an [`operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool) that should be used automatically by the compiler.